# Unable to receive push notifications with Ionic and Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to receive push notifications with Ionic and Cordova, but I'm unable to locate where the error occurs, because everything seems to be running smoothly.

First of all, I'm starting a new and clean Ionic project for debugging's sake. These are my exact commands:

```
ionic start myApp tabs
cd myApp
ionic platform add ios
cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="XXXXXXX"
```

Then I'm adding this to the `$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){...})` block:

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: "true",
        sound: "true"
    }
  });

push.on('registration', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

push.on('notification', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

push.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Which logs this to the Xcode console:

```
Push Plugin register success: <xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx>
2016-03-26 00:51:49.286 HelloCordova[913:278481] {"registrationId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

But when I'm trying to use apn in Node.js to send notifications, they are never received, even though no errors occur in Node. I'm not able to receive the notifications by using the APN Tester from the Mac app store either, even though everything seems to be running fine there too.

When I'm testing my key.pem and cert.pem files as suggested by the phonegap-plugin-push documentation, I get this:

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert cert.pem -key key.pem
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./CN=gateway.push.apple.com
   i:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
 1 s:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
   i:/O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
**VERY LONG CERTIFICATE**
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./CN=gateway.push.apple.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Certification Authority/CN=Apple Root CA
/C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations/CN=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
/C=US/O=Apple Inc./OU=Apple Certification Authority/CN=Apple Application Integration Certification Authority
---
SSL handshake has read 3144 bytes and written 2148 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: **MY-MASTER-KEY**
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1458949317
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
closed
```

Any suggestions to why this is not giving the expected results would be appreciated.